# update mac file creation time

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I am trying to update the mac files created, modified, last opened files timing.

For modified and last opened I tried below

```
touch -mt YYYYMMDDhhmm *
```

This is working fine.

Now for createed, I tried

```
touch -t YYYYMMDDhhmm *
```

but its not changing the created time.

I also tried `touch -ct YYYYMMDDhhmm *` but no luck.

Any idea why this is happening.

Also is there any way where using one command the folder and files inside folder/ subfolder timing will also get updated?

I have updated latest version of Mavericks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is problem with Mavericks or what, but `touch -mt` OR `touch -t` just update the modified and last opened  time.

Maybe `touch -mt` OR `touch -t` commands are working with 10.8.4 and earlier.

For Mavericks, I found solution as below.

```
SetFile -d '12/31/1999 23:59:59' file.txt
            MM dd yyyy hh mm ss  fileName
```

To update all files in folder just use

```
SetFile -d '12/31/1999 23:59:59' *
```

### [Reference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99599)